# How to extract mutlple fields from a json documet with Python?

Tags: python, json

I need to get only specific fields from my json document which is lat, long and timestamp.  This json file is a result of RESTful API. I came across how to extricate only one field.

Json documet:
    {'info': {'satname': 'SPACE STATION', 'satid': 25544, 'transactionscount': 
    0}, 'positions': [{'satlatitude': 28.89539607, 'satlongitude': 90.44547739, 
    'sataltitude': 420.36, 'azimuth': 12.46, 'elevation': -52.81, 'ra': 
    215.55022984, 'dec': -5.00234017, 'timestamp': 1591196844, 'eclipsed': 
    True}]}

```
 Here is my try:

URL = "url"
def data_collection():
  data = requests.get(url = URL).json() 

  del data['positions'][1]

  print(data)
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(data_collection)


while True:
 schedule.run_pending()
 time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You're mixing up arrays and dictionaries. You don't need the index, just the key name for a dictionary: `data['positions']['lat']`

Comment: @hmm, you mean I get three fields together at once

Comment: @user You're a new user so here is some advice. Ask one question at a time. If someone helps you solve one problem. Mark the answer as solved. If you have an additional question ask a new one. Don't totally delete the original question to ask something new.

Comment: So Sorry!! Thanks for the advice..

Answer (score 2):

```
def data_collection():
  data = requests.get(url = URL).json() 
  print([ data['positions'][0][x] for x in ('satlatitude', 'satlongitude', 'timestamp') ])
```

Comment: I like your answer because of its succinctness but it could be improved with some explanation of what it does. A list comprehension probably isn't beginner friendly.

Comment: @scotty3785 that's an opportunity for the beginner to learn about list comprehensions, one of the greatest Python idioms :-)

Comment: @Błotosmętek, I get this error:     print([data['positions'][x] for x in ('lat', 'long', 'timestamp') ])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @Błotosmętek, sorry my bad, I added some sample data. Here is complete data: [[{'satlatitude': 49.39039482, 'satlongitude': 52.01438497, 'sataltitude': 423.7, 'azimuth': 31.61, 'elevation': -36.81, 'ra': 195.69961379, 'dec': 6.46505414, 'timestamp': 1591196270, 'eclipsed': False}]]

Comment: @Błotosmętek, OMG it's working, out put is : [-14.14462281, 123.96107943, 1591197709]. I don't see curly brackets . Is it ok? Do we hav eto have {} around json always?

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the value of data each time you read a different field and as far as I can tell from your example, there is no list inside the JSON data so why are you accessing it with an index?

Change your code from

```
data = data['positions'][0]['lat']
data = data['positions'][1]['long']
data = data ['positions'][4]['timestamp']
```

to

```
lat = data['positions']['lat']
long = data['positions']['long']
timestamp = data ['positions']['timestamp']
```

Comment: @sotty How do I get these three as a json document. I need this result into a json document?

Comment: @user Wasn't part of your original question. Perhaps you can edit your question to show the example output you want or raise a new question to ask about this new requirement that you've added.

Comment: I updated my question. And I apologize for earlier question!!